# date based condition in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I tried the below code in my where condition in sql server and it is working. When i try to implement the same in `SSIS` conditional split transformation i am getting errors. Can anyone please guide me to correct syntax in `SSIS` condition?

```
[A_date] >= DATEADD(d,0,GETDATE())  - 14
```

Thanks

Comment: *" i am getting errors"*. And those errors are..? Please do share them. Thank you.

Comment: What is the hidden knowledge behind adding 0 days?

Comment: Error at Data Flow Task [Conditional Split [140]]: Attempt to find the input column named "d" failed with error code 0xC0010009. The input column specified was not found in the input column collection.

Comment: `DATEADD(d,0,GETDATE())  - 14` should be `DATEADD(day,-14,GETDATE())`. Shorthand operators are hard to remember, and this is far more clear and doesn't use integer subtraction from date objects. This will creep up and mess with you later, so it's best to *never* do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the condition you're looking a date that is on or after 14 days prior to the current date?  If so, the expression below verifies this.  In SSIS, the `datepart` parameter requires quotes.  While the abbreviation of `D` can be used instead of `DAY`, I'd recommend using `DAY` for clarity.

```
[A_date] >= DATEADD("DAY",-14,GETDATE())
```

**Update for null evaluation error:**

This is caused by a null column.  Any condition in a Conditional Split must return either true or false, and null returns neither of these thus leads to the error you received.  Use the `REPLACENULL` function to replace any nulls with a default value depending on how you want to evaluate these.  For example, if you want to treat all nulls in `A_date` as the current date use the expression below.

```
REPLACENULL([A_date], GETDATE()) >= DATEADD("DAY",-14,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks @userfl89 the syntax has been accepted.Checking the output.

Comment: Getting below error ---- [Conditional Split [2]] Error: The expression "[A_date] >= DATEADD("DAY",-14,GETDATE())" on "Conditional Split.Outputs[Case 1]" evaluated to NULL, but the "Conditional Split" requires a Boolean results. Modify the error row disposition on the output to treat this result as False (Ignore Failure) or to redirect this row to the error output (Redirect Row).  The expression results must be Boolean for a Conditional Split.  A NULL expression result is an error.

Comment: @abhi234u please see my updated answer for an explanation of the error.

Comment: Thanks userfl89. I created two conditions and one is with ISNULL and other as above. Appreciate all the users above for your inputs.